# bokeh package in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, bokeh

when I use bokeh in eclipse like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
```

the console show:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen'
```

How can I deal with it?
By the way,when I use bokeh in spyder or notebook,nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The only place in the entire Bokeh codebase that uses `urlopen` (from `six`), is here:

```
❯ grip urlopen
./sampledata/__init__.py:
    8 : from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
   87 :     url = urlopen(file_url)
```

In one of the sampledata files, which you do not appear to be using anyway. Offhand, just to be certain, you can make sure the library `six` is installed. If that does not solve the problem, then the issue is something to do with Eclipse (or maybe a python-related Eclipse plugin you have installed) and not with Bokeh.